# Confused about Functions

Tags: python, area

So I'm currently doing an assignment for my python coding class and I have to get the area of a cylinder and I'm supposed to be using functions so it looks cleaner, but I'm not so sure how to exactly do my assignment from scratch, I've watched a lot of videos but can't really seem to understand functions, my code looks like this currently, but whenever I run my code I can't get the "def calc():" part to run, could I get some pointers please?

```
def info():
    r = float(input("What is the radius of the cylinder? "))
    h = float(input("What is the height of the cylinder? "))
    print("The cylinders area is", area)

def calc():
    pi = 22/7
    area = ((2*pi*r) * h) + ((pi*r**2)*2)
    return pi, area

info()
```

Comment: Hi, the last line in info() should be `print("The cylinder's area is ", str(calc(r, h)))`. And you should also change `def calc():` to `def calc(r, h):`. ***Note the casting to str!*** And you shouldn't return the `pi`. Only return `area`. That's the only thing you need.

Answer (score 1):

Don't need so many funcatin .

```
def info():
    r = float(input("What is the radius of the cylinder? "))
    h = float(input("What is the height of the cylinder? "))
    calc(r,h)
    

def calc(r,h):
    pi = 22/7
    area = ((2*pi*r) * h) + ((pi*r**2)*2)
    print("The cylinders area is", area)
    

info()
```

Answer (score 0):

in this case I put the radius as 3 and height as 6. You need to define you variables.
Then it should work. in this case I used numpy to import an exact pi variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the `calc()` function above the `info()` function. You have to actually call the `calc()` function which will return the area of cylinder. I have provided the code below which should solve your problem. Hope you understand the code!

```
def calc(r, h): # Calculates the area of cylinder
    pi = 22/7
    area = ((2*pi*r) * h) + ((pi*r**2)*2)
    return area

def info(): # Takes the radius and height from user.
       r = float(input("What is the radius of the cylinder? "))
       h = float(input("What is the height of the cylinder? "))
       
       return f"The area is {calc(r, h)}"
 
# r = 5
# h = 10   
print(info())

# using parameters in functions instead of inputs:

def info2(r, h):
    return f"The area is {calc(r, h)}"

r = 5
h = 10 
print(info2(r, h))

# Comparing areas of cylinders

area1 = calc(5, 10)
area2 = calc(10, 15)

if area1>area2: #Area1 is greater than Area2
    print("Area1 is greater than Area2")
elif area2>area1: #Area2 is greater than Area1
    print("Area2 is greater than Area1")
else: #Both are equal
    print("Both are equal")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have one more question if you don't mind helping me with, I'm trying to compare two cylinders to see which one is the bigger one, how would I go about doing so?

Comment: @LastCheck define another function that takes in areas of the two cylinder as arguements/parameters, compare the areas and return the bigger area.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: @LastCheck I have edited the answer to compare areas of two cylinders

Comment: Thanks so much for the help man, I really do appreciate the work you've put in to help me grow!

Comment: You're most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned in a comment that you wanted to input multiple cylinders and determine which was the larger one -- I think for that you want to have your function that inputs a cylinder return the cylinder itself so that it can be compared using the volume function.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from math import pi


@dataclass
class Cylinder:
    radius: float
    height: float
    name: str


def volume(c: Cylinder) -> float:
    return (2*pi*c.radius) * c.height + (pi*c.radius**2)*2


def input_cylinder(name: str) -> Cylinder:
    r = float(input(f"What is the radius of the {name} cylinder? "))
    h = float(input(f"What is the height of the {name} cylinder? "))
    return Cylinder(r, h, name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cylinders = [input_cylinder(name) for name in ('first', 'second')]
    for c in cylinders:
        print(f"The {c.name} cylinder's volume is {volume(c)}")
    print(f"The bigger cylinder is the {max(cylinders, key=volume).name} one.")
```